# keep showing that:"java.lang.NullPointerException"

Tags: java, nullpointerexception

I want to read contents from a text file and then set it to some variables in car class. But it keeps showing me that "java.lang.NullPointerException". I don't know what's wrong with it. Could someone tell me what to do?

The error line is `cars[0].setRegion(tokens[2]);`

Here's the text file.

CarInLot KLM456 ND Meter4 120

CarInLot VMK123 ME Moving 0

CarInLotDKC003 WA Meter5 30

Meter1 None 10

CarInLot IML84U ND Meter6 800

Here's the test class.

```
import java.util.Scanner; 
import java.io.*;         


public class test
{
   public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException
   {

      // Get the filename.

      String filename = "input.txt";

      // Open the file.
      File file = new File(filename);

      Scanner inputFile = new Scanner(file);

      Car[] cars = new Car[4];


      while (inputFile.hasNext())
      {

         String filecotent = inputFile.nextLine();

         String[] tokens = filecotent.split(" ");

         if(filecotent.startsWith("CarInLot")){

            cars[0].setRegion(tokens[2]);

            cars[0].setMinutes(Integer.parseInt(tokens[4]));
         }

         if(filecotent.startsWith("Meter")){

            cars[0].setPlate(tokens[1]);      
         }


      }
       System.out.println(cars[0].toString());

      // Close the file.
      inputFile.close();
   }


}
```

Here's car class.

```
public class Car {

    private String plate;
    private String region;
    private int minutes;

    public Car(String carPlate, String carRegion, 
               int carMinutes) {

        plate = carPlate;
        region = carRegion;
        minutes = carMinutes;
    }


    public Car(Car object2) {

        plate = object2.plate;
        region = object2.region;
        minutes = object2.minutes;
    }

    public void setPlate(String pl) {
        plate = pl;
    }

    public void setRegion(String re) {
        region = re;
    }

    public void setMinutes(int mi) {
        minutes = mi;
    }


    public String getPlate() {
        return plate;
    }

    public String getRegion() {
        return region;
    }

    public int getMinutes() {
        return minutes;
    }

    public String toString() {

        String string = "Car's information: " 
                        + "\n"
                        + "\nLicense Plate:    " + plate
                        + "\nLicense Plate Resgistration Region:    " + region
                        + "\nParked time" + minutes
                        + "\n";

        return string;

    }


}
```

Comment: Did the file also have those blank lines, or is that something you added for the question?

Comment: Show the exact error statement that you are receiving along with the lines that it is pointing to

Comment: Post the full error, with the stack trace.

Comment: Java teachers should let students write 100 times on the blackboard: "`new X[100]` does not create any X objects."

Answer (score 5, accepted):

So you've got this code

```
Car[] cars = new Car[4];

while (inputFile.hasNext())
{
    String filecotent = inputFile.nextLine();

    String[] tokens = filecotent.split(" ");

    if(filecotent.startsWith("CarInLot")){
        cars[0].setRegion(tokens[2]);
        cars[0].setMinutes(Integer.parseInt(tokens[4]));
    }
    ...
```

`cars` is initialized, but the elements inside it aren't. You need to initialize those first, otherwise they are `null` and you get `NullPointerException`.

```
cars[someIndex] = new Car(...);
```

Also, the way you have your code now, you'll always be overwriting the same `Car` reference in the array, ie. the one at index 0. You may want to use an incrementing index to initialize each element.